# Are processes triggered if a field is set to the same value as it held before?

Tags: apex, trigger, dml, dml-operations

An Apex method is called and updates the StageName field from 'Approved' to 'Documentation.' It completes. A different Apex method is called and 'updates' the StageName field on the same record from 'Documentation' to 'Documentation' (the same value). **Does this second 'update' trigger all processes that run on opportunity update?**

Reference/documentation is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any DML that contains at least one record causes [the Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) to be run.

You don't need to change any of the data in an update. The fact that you *are performing a DML update* is enough to cause the update train to start.

One distinction is that this just gives these processes (triggers, flow, workflow, validation rules, process builder) an *opportunity* to run. The criteria/decision nodes that you have in the other automation tools still determine whether or not they actually run.

Comment: And that is why one should always match old and new values to verify exact change  in apex and flows to before executing a block

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would fire all triggers/workflow rules for the second update.